# Pygame not updating when input keys are entered

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to get a shape to move when certain keys are entered, but for some reason, the shape isn't moving. I suspected that it was because the display was not being updated so I added the `pygame.display.update()`  function after the movement conditions to update it, but that didn't work. I tried rendering the shape in after the movement conditions as well but that didn't work either. I assume that I need to tell the code "what to move on keypress" but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Below is my code:

```
import sys

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
color = '#FFFFFF'

# Changing surface color
win.fill(color)
pygame.display.flip()

# shape stuff
x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 50

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        # circle

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel

    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0, 0, 255), (400, 250), width)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the circle at (`x`, `y`) rather than constantly at (400, 250):

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(win, (0, 0, 255), (400, 250), width)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y), width)
```